# Check enum for multiple values

Tags: java, enums, conditional-statements

I have an enum `FileType`

```
public static enum FileType {
  CSV, XML, XLS, TXT, FIXED_LENGTH
}

FileType fileType = FileType.CSV;
```

Is there a better (cleaner) way to check `fileType` for multiple values than the following (like `"myString".matches("a|b|c");`)?

```
if(fileType == FileType.CSV || fileType == FileType.TXT || fileType == FileType.FIXED_LENGTH) {}
```

Comment: An `EnumSet`? Or a boolean field on your `FileType` enum?

Comment: EnumSet is what you want to use in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up writing a method:

```
public static enum FileType {
  CSV, XML, XLS, TXT, FIXED_LENGTH;

  // Java < 8
  public boolean in(FileType... fileTypes) {
    for(FileType fileType : fileTypes) {
      if(this == fileType) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  // Java 8
  public boolean in(FileType... fileTypes) {
    return Arrays.stream(fileTypes).anyMatch(fileType -> fileType == this);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
if(fileType.in(FileType.CSV, FileType.TXT, FileType.FIXED_LENGTH)) {}
```

Nice and clean!

Comment: This is basically the same thing as what a few other people suggested. It'd be nice if you accepted their answer since they took the time to help you out.

Comment: can you explain how `fileType == this` worked

Comment: This doesn't work. You've created an instance of the enum?? Since you've written `fileType.in` rather than `FileType.in`. Otherwise the functions also need to be static and then 'this' does not work as Rajat pointed out.

Comment: @Rajat @Hasen `fileType` is an instance of the class you want to check against one or many file types (here `CSV`, `TXT`, `FIXED_LENGTH`). Since its an instance, the method `in()` is _not_ static and `this` can be used.

Answer (score 29):

Option 1: Add a boolean field to your enum.

```
public static enum FileType {
    CSV(true), XML(false), XLS(false), TXT(true), FIXED_LENGTH(true);

    private final boolean interesting;

    FileType(boolean interesting) {
        this.interesting = interesting;
    }
    public boolean isInteresting() {
        return this.interesting;
    }
}

...

if (fileType!=null && fileType.isInteresting()) {
    ...
}
```

Option 2: use an [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).
`EnumSets` use bitfields under the hood, so they are very fast and low memory.

```
Set<FileType> interestingFileTypes = EnumSet.of(FileType.CSV, FileType.TXT, FileType.FIXED_LENGTH);
...
if (interestingFileTypes.contains(fileType)) {
   ...
}
```

Option 3: use a `switch`, as kocko suggests

Comment: + 1 for mentioning the EnumSet. Note that an `EnumSet` is just another implementation of `Set` so you can write: `Set<FileType> interestingFileTypes = EnumSet.of(...);`

Answer (score 16):

Why not use a `switch`:

```
switch(fileType) {
   case CSV:
   case TXT:
   case FIXED_LENGTH:
       doSomething();
       break;
}
```

This does the same as your if statement check, but it's more readable, imho.

But the problem with this code is not the `switch` or the `if/else` statement(s). The problem is that it breaks the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

In order to fix that, I would completely remove the `enum` and create an interface:

```
interface FileType {
   boolean isInteresting();
}
```

Then, for each enum constant we used to have, I would create a separate interface implementation:

```
public class Txt implements FileType {
  @Override
  public boolean isInteresting() {
    return false;
  } 
}
```

How does the `switch` statement change? We used to pass a `fileType` parameter, on which we checked the value. Now, we will pass an instance of `FileType`.

```
public void method(FileType fileType) {
  if (fileType.isInteresting()) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that when you introduce a new `FileType` (which you would introduce as a new enum constant), you don't have to modify the `switch`/`if/else` statement to handle the case when this new file type is interesting or not. The code will simply work here without modification, which is the essence of the Open-closed principle: "Open for extensions, closed for modifications".

Comment: That's even worse, instead of using one long line it uses loads of lines and makes your code look so much longer.

Comment: @Hasen, what is actually worse here, is that the `switch` statement (and also the if/else aprpoach) is breaking the Open-closed principle in OOP. So in this case I would actually throw away the enum and the if/else/switch statements and use an interface `FileType` with a few implementations, instead. But note that I've written this answer 7 years ago. :) :)

Comment: @Hasen, I updated my answer, now it's actually even better. Long story short: Avoid using enums and switch statements. These bring more issues than you would think. :)

Answer (score -1):

Adding a different example:

```
public class JavaApplication {

    public enum CustomerStatus {
        ACTIVE("Active"),
        DISCONNECTED("Disconnected"),
        PENDING("Pending"),
        CANCELLED("cancelled"),
        NEW("new");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumSet<CustomerStatus> setA = EnumSet.of(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE, CustomerStatus.NEW);
        EnumSet<CustomerStatus> setB = EnumSet.of(CustomerStatus.PENDING, CustomerStatus.CANCELLED);
        if (setA.contains(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE)) {
            System.out.println("ACTIVE : customer active");
        }
        if (setB.contains(CustomerStatus.ACTIVE)) {
            System.out.println("ACTIVE: Customer is no longer active");
        }
        if (setB.contains(CustomerStatus.CANCELLED)   {
            System.out.println("CANCELLED: Customer is no longer active");
        }

    }
}


**Output**:
ACTIVE : customer active
CANCELLED: Customer is no longer active
```